# Pastespecial pasting only the first cell value across entire range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste the formula results from one column to the next. I need to perform this through a macro without using a loop as it slows down the tool due to large number of records. The following methods are not working -

```
a) range("G5:G10").value = range("H5:H10").value  
b) Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The issue is that excel copies the formula result of the first cell ("G5") to all the cells at the destination ("H5:H10"). The formula in the source is an array formula. Could anyone please share how to resolve the issue.

Edit :

```
    Sub paste()
'
' paste Macro
'

'
Dim ColName As String, sheetname1 As String, lookup_col As String, lastrow_range As Long
ColName = "A"
sheetname1 = "Sheet1"
lookup_col = "C"
lastrow_range = 8

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaArray = _
         "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE,EXACT($" & ColName & ActiveCell.Row & "," & sheetname1 & "!$" & lookup_col & "$5:$" & lookup_col & "$" & lastrow_range & "),0)) ,  ""-" & ColName & """&"" is Invalid. This should match with any one of the values in column "" &""" & lookup_col & """&"" of "" & """ & sheetname1 & """&"". Please refer ""&""" & sheet_name & """ ,""It Matches"")"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F5:F8")

    Range("F5:F8").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `.value=.value` will never copy the formulas across. Avoid using `Selection.PasteSpecial`. Use the complete address where you want to paste. Your "Selection" may not be the selection that you think it is? Something like `range("G5:G10").Copy` and then `range("H5:H10").Pastespecial...`

Comment: I think you can do `range("G5:G10").formula = range("H5:H10").formula`  ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Siddharth, thanks for the input. I'm trying to copy the text results of the input column formulas i.e the destination should not have a formula that is deriving the result. It seems to be working when I copy the formulas using ".Copy".

Comment: @TimWilliams - Tim, thanks for the input. I'm trying to copy only the text results so the destination column only has text values. It is so strange that when I try to do it from front end it works, when I copy the recorded macro from front end to the vb, it does not work and pastes only the result of the first cell across the entire column.

Comment: Then `range("G5:G10").value = range("H5:H10").value` should work. Ensure you fully qualify the range. For example `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G5:G10").value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H5:H10").value`

Comment: @SiddharthRout,thanks, I tried but it's not working. I've added a snippet of the code that is causing the issue. It does a case-sensitive comparison of two columns. If you place the first column data in A5:A8 and second column data in C5:C8, it will update the result in F5:F8. But the results are wrong.

Comment: I just tested your code and it copies the values of Col F to Col G correctly

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste special values of range

```
Range("H5:H10").Copy
Range("G5:G10").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Copy and paste range

```
Range("H5:H10").Copy
Range("G5:G10").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Or copy and paste the entire column

```
Range("H:H").Copy
Range("G:G").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input.
I found that the calculation method had to be changed to 'Automatic' from 'Manual' :

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic